# Implementing DCT2/DCT3 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, jpeg, dct

I am having some issues with my code for doing the final implementation for a data to image library using the JPEG DCT2/3 process. Linked below is the source code that I am using. I am using the python code under the SageMathCloud. I've been trying to figure out this specific error for the past several hours, and no matter how I do it, it just doesn't work. I get the same error message everytime, and I just can't track down the reason why.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/nick5435/43871b69ae963ff038db3b38dd3ecac8)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error you are getting...

Comment: It's all listed in the gist.

Comment: I see.  `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions` seems pretty evident - I guess put in some print statements to see where you are changing the dimensions?  I'd especially see what `i` was when that loop fails.  But probably you can't concatenate one row after another in that way, since after the first one you'd have two different sizes being joined, if I read this correctly.  Sorry if this isn't helpful, it's really about how you're using numpy.